# getting values from a selected item in a dropdownlist in a table cell that was dynamically created in a table in vb code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have created a table dynamically on an asp.net page by creating the rows based of off the number of rows in a dataset from a SQL database. I used a for loop to create my rows and cells with the populated dropdownlists in the page_load() function. My table is created exactly how it needs to be, but I need to get the selected item text for each cell in every row to store back to a database table upon clicking the submit button. I initially have a placeholder on my asp page and replace it with the created table on load. For some reason, when i try to use

For Each r As TableRow In LineupTable.Rows

```
 msgbox(EmployeeDDL.SelectedItem.Text)
```

Next r

it gives me a null value error for employeeddl.selecteditem.text.

This is how I generate my table.

'Dynamically create table rows and cells and populate them with the proper controls and/or information

```
        Dim numrows As Integer = dtEQP.Rows.Count
        Dim numcells As Integer = 6
        Dim j As Integer


        For j = 0 To numrows - 1
            r = New TableRow()
            c1 = New TableCell() With {.Width = 300}
            c1.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(dtEQP.Rows(j).ItemArray(0)))
            r.Cells.Add(c1)

            c2 = New TableCell() With {.Width = 200}
        Dim EmployeeDDL As New DropDownList()
        EmployeeDDL.DataSource = dsEMP
        EmployeeDDL.DataTextField = "FirstName"
        EmployeeDDL.DataValueField = "ID"
        EmployeeDDL.DataBind()
        EmployeeDDL.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("", "-1"))
        c2.Controls.Add(EmployeeDDL)
            r.Cells.Add(c2)

            c3 = New TableCell() With {.Width = 180}
            Dim CodeDDL As New DropDownList()
            CodeDDL.Items.Add("0-Running")
            CodeDDL.Items.Add("99-Idle")
            CodeDDL.Items.Add("60-Down")
            CodeDDL.Items.Add("1-Weather")
            CodeDDL.SelectedValue = "99-Idle"
            c3.Controls.Add(CodeDDL)
            r.Cells.Add(c3)

            c4 = New TableCell() With {.Width = 100}
            Dim RideDDL1 As New DropDownList()
            RideDDL1.DataSource = dsRide
            RideDDL1.DataTextField = "Ridename"
            RideDDL1.DataValueField = "RideID"
            RideDDL1.DataBind()
            RideDDL1.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("", "-1"))
            c4.Controls.Add(RideDDL1)
            r.Cells.Add(c4)

            c5 = New TableCell() With {.Width = 200}
            Dim OTddl1 As New DropDownList()
            OTddl1.DataSource = dsEMP2
            OTddl1.DataTextField = "FirstName"
            OTddl1.DataValueField = "ID"
            OTddl1.DataBind()
            OTddl1.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("", "-1"))
            c5.Controls.Add(OTddl1)
            r.Cells.Add(c5)


            c6 = New TableCell() With {.Width = 350}
            Dim CommentsTxtBx As New TextBox()
            c6.Controls.Add(CommentsTxtBx)
            r.Cells.Add(c6)


            LineupTable.Rows.Add(r)
        Next j
```

Any ideas on how I should be retrieving this value in my on click subroutine to get what was actually selected?

Comment: Where are you creating the controls? where are you calling your loop to get the selected item? This looks likely to be a problem of page life cycle.

Comment: Creating the controls, table, tablerows, and table cells in the page_load(); calling my loop to get the selected items in my save_click()

Comment: Keep in mind the page load occurs before your button click, so if you recreate the controls on pageload, they are blank by the time they get to the click event, also if you don't create your controls on postback, they wont exist, you need to create your controls in oninit.  [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx] is a good document to learn about the page life cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First when you add the DropDownList, give it an ID (use your cursor variable to avoid having a duplicate ID):

```
EmployeeDDL.ID = "EmployeeDDL" & j.ToString()
```

Secondly, since the DropDownList was dynamically added you need to use FindControl to get an instance of it.  Also, make sure SelectedItem is not null/nothing.

```
Dim intCursor As Integer = 0
For Each r As TableRow In LineupTable.Rows

    Dim ddlTarget As DropDownList = Cast(r.Cells(1).FindControl("EmployeeDDL" & intCursor.ToString()), DropDownList)

    If Not ddlTarget.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then

        Dim strValue = ddlTarget.SelectedItem.Text

    End If

    intCursor += 1

Next r
```

Comment: That still doesn't return any text. It's almost as if the selecteditem.text isn't changing its value once a new item has been selected. It just keeps returning the blank value that it was loaded with originally and giving me a null error.

Comment: This solution creates a problem with multiple rows having the same dropdownlist with the same ID because they were dynamically created the same way, and that causes a system crash and an error message when i try to click my button. I guess that I will have to find some way to program code in the background that will generate a unique id for each row created if I were going to fix it this way.